# 100% cpu load on nginx + php-fpm with prestashop 1.5.4

Tags: nginx, prestashop, vps, php

I managed to set up my VPS (single core CPU Speed:2.40 GHz Cache Size:512.00 KiB, 1 gig ram) with the prestashop/ubuntu 12.10 guide on [HowtoForge](http://www.howtoforge.com/running-prestashop-1.5.x-on-nginx-lemp-on-debian-wheezy-ubuntu-12.10). Everything is working, except for the extremely high CPU load, when 1 user opens 1 page the CPU loads shoots to 100% and still takes ~2seconds to process, I'm thinking there is something wrong in the php code, but I don't know how i can find out what is using up so much resources. Via htop I can see its php-fpm: pool, but that's not really helping me find out what is wrong with the code.

The php5-fpm log is showing me only this warning:

```
[12-Apr-2013 12:36:16] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (10), consider raising it
[12-Apr-2013 12:41:49] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (10), consider raising it
[12-Apr-2013 12:56:26] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (10), consider raising it
[12-Apr-2013 12:56:43] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (10), consider raising it
[12-Apr-2013 12:59:39] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (10), consider raising it
```

But as I did a little bit of looking around 10 isn't an unusual low number for this setting.

I'm wondering if anyone could help me on the way to find out what is causing this issue?

This is my website: [www.deepdevotionshop.com](http://www.deepdevotionshop.com)

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Not server config/tech support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to enable the profiling feature, it will highlight which part of the code is slowing down your server.

1. In your PrestaShop v1.5.4 store, edit /config/defines.inc.php
2. On line 44, replace `define('_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_', false);` by `define('_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_', true);`
3. Go to your store homepage and reload the page
4. You should now be able to see how much time is consuming each function and SQL query

Regards,
Bruno-